# Array.prototype.filter - Is it possible to filter multiple conditions with more than one criteria? [JS, VueJS]

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, ecmascript-6, nuxt.js

I have the following method on VueJS 2.0/Nuxt Application:

```
applyFilters(filterCriteria) {
  this.filtered = this.unfiltered.slice().filter((x) => {
    // Zona
    if (x.zona !== filterCriteria.zona) {
      return false
    }

    // Bairro
    for (const key in filterCriteria.bairro) {
      if (x.bairro !== filterCriteria.bairro[key]) {
        return false
      }
    }

    // Categoria
    for (const key in filterCriteria.categoria) {
      if (x.categoria !== filterCriteria.categoria[key]) {
        return false
      }
    }
    return true
  })
},
```

What I am trying to achieve is somehow filter multiple conditions based also on multiple criteria. Is that achievable with `.filter()`?

Whenever I apply the first criteria it works fine, and also when I apply the second it will work as well, but whenever I apply a second item to the second criteria, it just fails to filter and fallback to `false` everytime.

This works:

```
  filterCriteria: {
    zona: 'Germany',
    bairro: ['Berlin'],
    categoria: ['City']
  }
```

This won't:

```
  filterCriteria: {
    zona: 'Germany',
    bairro: ['Berlin', 'Munich'],
    categoria: ['City']
  }
```

Am I missing something or this won't work as expected?

Comment: It isn't clear what you expect from that second filter. The way you have it, it will return false if anything *does not* match. Is that what you want? Or do you want it to return true if any one *does* match?

Comment: @MarkMeyer Sorry for not being clear. The expected behavior is filter to any conditions in `bairro: 'Berlin', 'Munich']`, not every one of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use includes(). Array and String contains this method

```
applyFilters(filterCriteria) {
    this.filtered = this.unfiltered.slice().filter((x) => {
        // Zona
        if (x.zona !== filterCriteria.zona) {
           return false
        }

        // Bairro
        if (!filterCriteria.bairro.includes(x.bairro)) {
           return false
        }

        // Categoria
        if (!filterCriteria.categoria.includes(x.categoria)) {
           return false
        }

        return true
    })
},
```

Comment: doesn't iterate over multilples.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is

```
for (const key in filterCriteria.bairro) {
  if (x.bairro !== filterCriteria.bairro[key]) {
    return false
  }
}
```

you can't have one value equal to two different values.

That is, you can't have one value equal to `'Berlin'` and then also equal to `'Munich'`. So it will fail for sure.  Looks like the third check is going to have the same issue.

You can use `includes`, or another way is

```
if (!filterCriteria.bairro.some(v => v === x.bairro))
  return false;
```

and just a note: if you have a large array, you can use a `Set` instead so that the checking is fast.  It is like `myCities.has(thisCity)` and it is `O(1)` time.

Comment: How can I test for multiple values inside the for loop and yet consider the previous applied criterias?

Comment: Eugene has a great answer with includes - it is a great option to use here.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I've tried both `includes` and `some` and it works as expected. Can't believe the solution was this simple.